# C# Parse to the yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to Parse `Mon, 11 Mar 2019 09:13:16 +0100` to `2019-03-11T09:13:16`

```
string dataa = "Mon, 11 Mar 2019 09:13:16 +0100";
DateTime d = new DateTime();
d = DateTime.ParseExact(dataa,"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("data: "+d);
```

But the error is:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Is there any method to do this parsing automatically? Thanks to everyone.

**update**

As mentioned below, like the other users replied to me, I needed the function ToString(String, IFormatProvider) in the first place.

Comment: You've asked the computer to parse a string in the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss - but that's nothing like the format of the string you've provided (Mon, 11 Mar 2019 09:13:16 +0100). Note that a DateTime value doesn't have a format - it sounds like you want to perform two operations, the first parsing your original value to a DateTime, and the second *formatting* that DateTime back to a string.

Comment: Parsing is about taking a *string* and turning it into something else - here, a `DateTime`, at which point it doesn't **have** a format (being simply the count of 100ns intervals since the start of `01/01/0001`). You have a string that doesn't look like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`. You're not going to make much progress by trying to *parse* it and telling the system that that *is* what the string looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `ParseExact`, your string and format should match *exactly*.

The proper format is: `ddd, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz` (or `HH` which depends on your hour format)

After you parse it, you need to use `ToString` to format it with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` format (or `HH` which depends you want [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) or [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) format)

I think I have to add little bit more explanation that a lot of people confuse (specially who are beginner about programming).  A [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) instance does *not* have any format. It just have date and time values which is basicly a numeric value called [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2). When you talk about "format" concept, that points to *textual representation* which is `string`.

Since you said "`Mon, 11 Mar 2019 09:13:16 +0100` to `2019-03-11T09:13:16`", I (and probably a lot of people also) assume that you have a string as `Mon, 11 Mar 2019 09:13:16 +0100` and you want to get `2019-03-11T09:13:16` as a string from it. For that, you need to parse your string to DateTime first. For that, as you do, `ParseExact` is one option.

When you parse it to `DateTime`, you get it's *textual representation*, which is `string`, with `ToString` method. This method have a few overloads and you should use [`ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_). With that, you specify your output format as a first parameter, and your culture info as a second parameter which it *might* effect on your result string because of the `:` and `/` format specifiers since they can change based on the current culture or supplied culture.

Further reading: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the format that the input data has (the second parameter of `DateTime.ParseExact`). In your case, the data you provide has the format `ddd, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz`. Also, in the last line, where you print the result you have to format it.

So, this is how you have to do it:

```
string dataa = "Mon, 11 Mar 2019 09:13:16 +0100";
DateTime d = new DateTime();
d = DateTime.ParseExact(dataa, "ddd, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("data: " + d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"));
```